# Shell Script for comparing two folders

Tags: shell

I want to write a shell script to compare two folders and save the difference in a different folder.

Suppose FolderA has five sub folders as A1,A2,A3,A4,A5 and FolderB has five sub folders as A1,A2,A3,A4,A5. Both folders A & B are same in structure but the files inside folders A1,A2 and so on have some differences.

I want to compare the difference of the files in FolderA-> A1 with FolderB-> A1 and save the result in a folder Difference/A1. I tried to write the script but it's not working — please guide me?

```
    #!/bin/bash
    # setup folders for our different stages
    DIST=/app/webmcore1/Demo/FolderA
    DIST_OLD=/app/webmcore1/Demo/FolderB
    mkdir -p Difference/newAddition
    mkdir -p Difference/DifferenceIs
    DIST_UPGRADE=/app/webmcore1/Demo/Difference
    cd $DIST
    find . -type f | while read filename
    do
        if [ ! -f "$DIST_OLD$filename" ]; then
        cp --parents "$filename" $DIST_UPGRADE/newAddition
        continue
        fi
        diff "$filename" "$DIST_OLD$filename" > /app/webmcore1/Demo/DIST_UPGRADE/DifferenceIs
    done
```

Comment: You don't seem to cover files present in A but not present in B (files deleted). Your `diff` command writes to a file, but each difference overwrites any previous one.  You are not systematic in your use of names. `Differenece` is not the orthodox spelling of `Difference`.  In `"$DIST_OLD$filename"`, you are not inserting a slash between the components, so you end up looking for `/app/webmcore1/Demo/FolderB./A1/Somename` which typically won't exist.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, Thanks for your quick response. I did not get your second point. Can you kindly throw some more light on that.

Comment: Is there a reason the [dircmp](http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?dircmp+1) command won't work for you?

Comment: Your `diff file1 file2 > difference.is` command does not append to `difference.is`, so if there are 3 files that are different, at the end of the script, you have only the differences from the last command saved in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using ls command and after that get the difference.

```
cd FolderA
ls -R >/tmp/list1
cd FolderB
ls -R >/tmp/list2
diff /tmp/list1 /tmp/list2 >/tmp/difference.list
```

This logic you can customize as per your requirement.